# Set data attribute based on text of element?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

Is it possible to set the value of a `data-*` attribute based on the text of the HTML element? Schematically, this is what I have in mind:

```
<div data-text={this.text}>example</div>
```

resulting in `data-text="example"`.

I think it may be possible if you set an `id` and then get the element by that, like this:

```
<div id="exampleId" data-text={document.getElementById("exampleId").textContent}>example</div>
```

But this is *not* what I'm hoping for because it requires setting an `id` ahead of time (so may as well just set the `data` attribute ahead of time). What I'm aiming for avoids the need to set anything specific to the element ahead of time and uses a property of the element itself to set that.

Maybe this isn't even a well defined question! But figured I'd ask. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `querySelectorAll` and apply logic to each element that has a `data-text` attribute like this:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-text]")

elements.forEach(element => {
    element.setAttribute("data-text", element.innerText)
})
```